# How to fix plumber cannot pipe to undefind with pug

Tags: gulp, pug

While working on HTML markup, I use pug. However, gulp gives me an error: `Can't pipe to undefined`.

The part of the code with the problem:

```
gulp.task('pug', function(){
    return gulp.src('dev/pug/pages/*.pug')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(pug({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .on('error', notify.onError(function(error){
            return "Message to the notifier: " + error.message;
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dev'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload());
});
```

Comment: 3 questions: 1) Can you add the code that imports `pug`? That error message you get indicates that the term `pug(...)` evaluates to undefined, so perhaps the way of importing the module is somehow at fault here. 2) Did you also install `pug` with `npm install` properly? 3) Is this the only error message you're getting? If not, could you please post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: @gandreadis
Yes, of course. Code, that adds gulp is the following:

'var pug = require('gulp-pug');'

I've reinstalled 'npm install gulp-pug --save-dev' at least 3 times.

My stack trace:
'[23:46:49] Using gulpfile C:\pros\arhmuz\gulpfile.js
[23:46:49] Starting 'pug'...
[23:46:49] 'pug' errored after 24 ms
[23:46:49] Error in plugin 'plumber'
Message:
    Can't pipe to undefined'

Even after this error, pug files are compiled.

Comment: Hmm... not sure what the issue is. Have you tried doing the same task but without using `plumber` (so simply removing the 3rd line)?

Comment: @gandreadis
Problem was found. And it was a browserSync, raising this error. Thank you for help!

Comment: Great to hear that it's fixed :)